# Understanding operator precedence in php

Tags: php, operators, operator-precedence

I have the following code in production that appears to be causing an infinite loop.

```
 $z=1;
 while (!$apns = $this->getApns($streamContext) && $z < 11)
 {
    myerror_log("unable to conncect to apple. sleep for 2 seconds and try again");
    $z++;
    sleep(2);
 }
```

How are the precedence rules getting applied that cause this behavior?

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

I see this note in the docs:

> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will
>   still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in
>   which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

Which makes me think the the = should be evaluated first.  then the ! then the &&, which would not cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Did you mean to use `==` (comparison) rather than `=` (assignment) in your while loop?

Comment: no, that statement really just means that `!` on the left of `=` is valid. The `&&` is still part of the value being assigned.

Comment: also: NO. BAD. Don't code like that. It's hideous.

Comment: it is allways a good idea to add some parentheses, so that the code is clear without these questions...

Comment: I know the code is bad...   It isn't even mine.  But the question is interesting.  I have an infinite loop here.   Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is evaluating like this:

```
while (!($apns = ($this->getApns($streamContext) && ($z < 11))))
```

which is why you see the infinite loop (as soon as `$z >= 11`, `$apns` is false, so the condition is always true). The reason for this precedence is that the special rules only apply to `!` on the *left* of the assignment being valid (having lower precedence than `=`). It has no effect on the boolean operator on the right, which behaves as it would in any sane language.

Your style is bad. Try this, which is much more readable and only differs in the final value of `$z` (and if that's important you can tweak the `break` statement.

```
for( $z = 1; $z < 11; ++ $z ) {
    // note extra brackets to make it clear that we intend to do assignment not comparison
    if( ($apns = $this->getApns($streamContext)) ) {
        break;
    }
    myerror_log("unable to conncect to apple. sleep for 2 seconds and try again");
    sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: So it seems to me that $apns would never have anything assigned other than a boolean value.  Right?  The rest of the code that connects to apple and send the push message would never work.

Comment: `$apns` would get whatever `getApns` returns. This is a common pattern; it is effectively waiting until `$apns` is truthy (i.e. non-null) then continuing with the code. Note that since the comparison is applied after assignment, it has no effect on the value which is in `$apns`. But if you want to make that clearer by splitting the assignment from the condition, that is also good.

Comment: Contrary to my earlier comment (now edited), PHP's `&&` and `||` *do* convert the values to `true` or `false`, so your initial code would always have put a `true` or `false` in `$apns`, meaning it would never work. The code I posted will work.

Comment: The `!` operator has higher precedence of all other operators in the expression. 
It is the first thing that will be evaluated, and will have no meaning. The outcome of `!$apns = $this->getApns($streamContext) && ($z < 11)`  is the same as `$apns = $this->getApns($streamContext) && ($z < 11)`. For example, try this code `!$a = true; echo $a;`. The value of `$a` will be `true`, not `false`.

Comment: @hdvianna that's the exact situation which the docs the OP references is talking about. It seems to be a special case in PHP (there are so many). I haven't tested though, so I could have misinterpreted it.

Comment: @Dave Yes, it has a special case. I didn't knew it =(. I've tested the code: `if (!$a = true) { echo "=)<br />"; } echo "\$a: $a<br />";` It will not print `=)`, though the value of `$a` will be `true` in the end.

Comment: @hdvianna don't worry about it. PHP is a complete mess of silly things like that. There are lots of pages on the internet dedicated to ranting about its bizarre special-cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is clear example of why it's good habit to **always** put all the conditions in brackets (and the same applies to code block. Even oneliners should be surrounded by `{` and `}`). So instead of error-prone:

```
while (!$apns = $this->getApns($streamContext) && $z < 11)
```

do

```
while (!($apns = $this->getApns($streamContext)) && ($z < 11))
```

and you will be safe.